# setOnClickListener function not folding correctly in android studio

Tags: android

when trying to fold this code fragment

```
ib_minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = tv_quantity.getText().toString();
                int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
                val--;
                if (val <= 0)
                    val = 0;
                tv_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(val));
            }
        });
```

it looks like that

```
    ib_minus.setOnClickListener((v)-> {

                String s = tv_quantity.getText().toString();
                int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
                val--;
                if (val <= 0)
                    val = 0;
                tv_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(val));

        });
```

how to fix that and make onclick body also fold?

Comment: Its an anonymous class. I don't think there is a way to fold anonymous class in Intellij IDEA. But you can file an issue and explain [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)...and @Daryl What is the problem? He asked correct question.

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around by doing custom region, just adding extra curly brackets to on click body and inside that block press shift+control+period. this also works for other listener functions

```
ib_minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {{
            String s = tv_quantity.getText().toString();
            int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
            val--;
            if (val <= 0)
                val = 0;
            tv_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(val));
        }}
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395783/3830694) is good. Alternatively, You can add region comments that can help you for folding:

for example :

```
//region
ib_minus.setOnClickListener((v)-> { 

                String s = tv_quantity.getText().toString(); 
                int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
                val--;
                if (val <= 0)
                    val = 0;
                tv_quantity.setText(Integer.toString(val));

        });
//endregion
```

Will fold entire code blocks between `//region` and `//endregion`.
Just press `Ctrl + Alt + T` to add region comments.
See [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-folding.html) for more info.